# convert string to point name

Tags: wpf, string, point

I have:

```
for(int b = 0; b <num; b++)
{
    string naz_pkt = "punkt_" + b.ToString();

    Point naz_pkt = new Point(i,j);
    ....
}
```

And what, I need to do:

I want make Points, where name of the Point will be change with the loop. And i will have for ex.

```
Point punkt_1 = new Point(0,1);
Point punkt_2 = new Point(0,2);
Point punkt_3 = new Point(0,3);
etc.
```

After that I want drow this points by polygon.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Thats not possible, but you should consider taking a List of Points (`List<Point>`) or a Point-array (`Point[]`) where you can store, read or manipulate the points. You could also create your own class, which contains a Name- and a Point-Property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really care about the name of the points, you can use a list to hold them:

```
List<Point> allPoints = new List<Point>();
for(int b = 0; b < num; b++)
{
    Point naz_pkt = new Point(i,j);
    allPoints.Add(naz_pkt);
}
```

If you care about the name you can use something like KeyValuePair:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Point>> allPoints = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Point>>();
for (int b = 0; b < num; b++)
{
    var pointName = "punkt_" + b.ToString();
    var pointObject = new Point(i, j);
    KeyValuePair<string, Point> point = new KeyValuePair<string, Point>(pointName, pointObject);

    allPoints.Add(point);
}
```